# How do I book flights Boston area to St. Thomas to Seattle to Boston area?

Tags: air-travel

How do I book flights Boston area to St. Thomas to Seattle to Boston area?

Which site allows me to put in this A to B to C to A itinerary for cost and convenience comparisons?

Answer (score 2):

This is called a multicity or multi stop itinerary. It can be booked on most online travel agents, or directly with most carriers serving all three ports.